# Angular 5 global undefined variable

Tags: javascript, angular

fellow coders!

I am trying to make injectable global variables.
However, when I try to use them, they are recognised as undefined.

My global.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class Globals {

  test: string = 'user';

}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Globals } from './globals'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [ Globals ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and the mycomponent.component.ts:

```
import { Globals } from '../globals';

@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.css'],
  providers: [ Globals ]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  test: string;

  constructor(private globals: Globals) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  myFunction() {
    console.log(Globals.test);
    this.test = Globals.test;
    console.log(this.test);
    if(this.test==Globals.test) alert("finally defined!");
  }
```

All of my console logs return me "undefined" (the alert does not appear as well). Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove providers: [ Globals ] from your component

Comment: Still the same.
Now the console returns this:
"src/app/mycomponent/mycomponent.component.ts(33,63): error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'typeof Globals'."

Comment: and use this.globals instead of Globals    change console.log(Globals.test); to console.log(this.globals.test);

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped!